# how to exclude a string from php regex search

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to exclude the `as` word from `abc.id as od`using preg_match();
Could anyone help me what will be the pattern?

Desired result is:

> `abc.id` as `od`

Hightlighed as the selection and `as` is excluded from search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* pattern to select the string :

```
(.*?)(?:\sas\s)(.*?)$
```

­

```
input        >>  abc.id as od
regex search >>  (.*?)(?:\sas\s)(.*?)$
replace with >>  $1$2
output       >>  abc.idod
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sQyW4n/1)

**PHP**

```
$re = '/(.*?)(?:\sas\s)(.*?)$/';
$str = 'abc.id as od';
$subst = '$1$2';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```